# XSLT avoid xmlns="" in XML element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm strugling to convert the documents attached. I've tried various scenario, but I think the problem is my leak of knoledge of XSLT and namespaces. I have to get the result in output avoiding xmlns="".
Thanks.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lid" select="SyncItemMaster/DataArea/ItemMaster/ItemMasterHeader/ItemID/ID/@lid" />

    <xsl:variable name="itemId" select="SyncItemMaster/DataArea/ItemMaster/ItemMasterHeader/ItemID/ID" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="SyncItemMaster" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" >
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.10.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncItemMaster.xsd</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:namespace name="xsd" select = "'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />

    <xsl:attribute name="versionID">2.10.x</xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

    </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="SyncItemMaster/ApplicationArea/Sender/LogicalID">
        <xsl:element name="LogicalID"><xsl:value-of select="$lid"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SyncItemMaster/ApplicationArea/Sender/ComponentID">
        <xsl:element name="ComponentID">erp</xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SyncItemMaster/ApplicationArea/BODID">
        <xsl:element name="BODID"><xsl:value-of select="concat( 'infor-nid:infor:', '515' , '::' ,$itemId, ':' , '?ItemMaster&amp;verb=Sync' )"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hello, here the Input I want to convert. SyncMatserItem has his own correct namespaces but I have to get of rid xmlns="" from all descending elements e.g.  , .

```
<SyncItemMaster releaseID="9.2">
<ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
        <LogicalID>infor.databaseion_app_6916_Advoco_LN_To_EAM_SyncItemMaster</LogicalID>
        <ComponentID>External</ComponentID>
        <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-11-20T16:14:38.747Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor.databaseion_app_6916_Advoco_LN_To_EAM_SyncItemMaster:1574266478747:12561:0</BODID>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID>515</AccountingEntityID>
        <LocationID/>
    <ActionCriteria>
        <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
    </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <ItemMaster>
        <ItemMasterHeader>
    <ItemID>
        <ID accountingEntity="515" lid="lid://infor.ln.ln_brubln03_comp-515" variationID="41759">G33167</ID>
    </ItemID>
        </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
</DataArea></SyncItemMaster>
```

Here, the actual output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.10.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncItemMaster.xsd" versionID="2.10.x" releaseID="9.2">
  <ApplicationArea xmlns="">
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID>lid://infor.ln.ln_brubln03_comp-515</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID>erp</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2019-11-20T16:14:38.747Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor-nid:infor:515::G33167:?ItemMaster&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea xmlns="">
...
```

Comment: Please show an example of the input and the expected output, so we can reproduce your problem - see: [mcve]. -- Also clarify with version of XSLT you're using: your question is tagged `xslt-1.0` but your stylesheet says `version="2.0"`.

Comment: The key to this is to think in terms of what you want the names of your elements to be (where the name is a [namespace, local-name] pair). If you create your elements in the right namespace, the namespace declarations in the serialized output will take care of themselves. The `xmlns=""` undeclarations arise when you create a parent element in a namespace, and a child element in no namespace.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got how to post code now :-).

Comment: You did not post the expected output. And you did not clarify which version of XSLT you're using. Why is it necessary to ask twice?

Comment: Michael, the version is the first line of XSLT above I suppose: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> so 2.0 ?

Again: the expected Output is in just above the comments ... avoiding xmlns="" in ApplicationArea and DataArea

Comment: Michael now is tagget correctly .

Comment: All I see is the actual output, not the expected one (the output you want to get).

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheet has an instruction:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="SyncItemMaster" xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" >
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.10.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncItemMaster.xsd</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:namespace name="xsd" select = "'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />
```

which creates creates a root element named `SyncItemMaster` that is in the `http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2` namespace:

```
<SyncItemMaster xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.10.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncItemMaster.xsd"
                versionID="2.10.x"/>
```

Then you have other templates that create other elements that will become children or descendants of the root element - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="SyncItemMaster/ApplicationArea/Sender/LogicalID">
    <xsl:element name="LogicalID"><xsl:value-of select="$lid"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

which creates an element named `LogicalID` that is in no-namespace. Such element will have an empty namespace declaration to signify that it does not inherit the default namespace of its parent/ancestor.

So, depending on your target schema, either put all the other elements in the same namespace as the root element, or do not put the root element in a namespace.

---

### Added:

I am guessing (!) you want to do the former, so try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version=".0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- MOVE ALL ELEMENTS TO THE DEFAULT NAMESPACE -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/SyncItemMaster">
    <SyncItemMaster xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.10.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncItemMaster.xsd">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </SyncItemMaster>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LogicalID">
    <LogicalID>
        <xsl:value-of select="/SyncItemMaster/DataArea/ItemMaster/ItemMasterHeader/ItemID/ID/@lid"/>
    </LogicalID>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ComponentID">
    <ComponentID>erp</ComponentID>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BODID">
    <BODID>
        <xsl:text>infor-nid:infor:515::</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/SyncItemMaster/DataArea/ItemMaster/ItemMasterHeader/ItemID/ID" />
        <xsl:text>:?ItemMaster&amp;verb=Sync</xsl:text>
    </BODID>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note the default namespace declaration in the `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag.

Comment: Thanks Michael, theory is now almost clear, can you post sample code to achive that? I have edit with Input and Output code.Tkx. Marco.

Comment: Michael, that works form me in XSLT 2.0 also, fine and thanks.